# How do I return data from Activity to calling class?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-activity, mobile-development

I have an Activity called `LoginActivity` which, in turn, creates an instance of `Auth` class, passing `this` to it (`Auth` has `context: Context` in constructor):

```
 override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        val authinstance = Auth(this);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login)
...
```

```
class Auth constructor(val context: Context) {
...
```

`Auth` in turn starts a new Activity:

```
 val intent = Intent(context, AuthWebViewActivity::class.java)
        intent.putExtra("url", url)
        startActivity(context,intent,null)
```

From `AuthWebViewActivity` some data must come back to `Auth`. How do I handle this? I am not sure that starting another Activity from a class like this is a good idea, there is probably a better way. However I would like to keep `AuthWebViewActivity` simple and handle all the authentication code in `Auth`.

Comment: A class like this can't be created and stored only in your Activity, because your Activity is ephemeral. By the time your other Activity returns, the first Activity may have been destroyed and recreated, so your original Auth instance will be gone and a new one will be created. You probably need to turn Auth into some kind of singleton, or have it back up its state to disk and always get its most recent state back from disk when a new one is instantiated. To deal with getting a result from another Activity in a mostly self-contained way, you can design your own ActivityResultContract for it to

Comment: expose to the first Activity to use. These are all big topics, too much to explain in an answer here, but you can look up the documentation and for tutorials on each of these individual subjects.